# Get runtime-created Label-Objects to return a value when clicked on

Tags: c#, events, object, click

I am creating a psychology experiment, in which a cluster of labels is displayed on the screen. 
In order to create the labels I have written a Class named **Stimulus** that holds parameters that I need to use/capture, and parameters to present a label on the screen. Hence - the screen/Form is populated by **stimulus-objects** that present as labels on the screen.

Here is the Stimulus Class:

```
class Stimulus
{
    public int myNumber { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Image myImage { get; set; }
    public int Pos_X { get; set; }
    public int Pos_Y { get; set; }
    public DateTime responseTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime endResponseTime { get; set; }
    public int currentTracker { get; set; }
    public bool clickTypeTrueFalse { get; set; }
    public Label stimulsLabel { get; set; }


    public Label addMyLabel()
    {
        Label myLabel = new Label();
        myLabel.Font = new Font("Ariel", 10);
        myLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        myLabel.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        myLabel.Text = Text;
        myLabel.Image = myImage; //will start with global::my_pTrials_01.Properties.Resources.myBlueCircle
        myLabel.Size = new Size(myLabel.Image.Width, myLabel.Image.Height);
        myLabel.Location = new Point(Pos_X, Pos_Y);

        return (myLabel);
    }
```

And here is the method that populates the Form with the object-created-labels:

```
private void CreateLabels(int[]Positions1, int[]Positions2, string[] stimulusLabels)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Positions1.Length; i++)
        {
            Stimulus thisStimulus = new Stimulus();
            thisStimulus.currentTracker = myTracker.mytracking;
            thisStimulus.myImage =    global::my_pTrials_01.Properties.Resources.myBlueCircle;
            thisStimulus.myNumber = i;
            thisStimulus.Pos_X = Positions1[i];
            thisStimulus.Pos_Y = Positions2[i];
            thisStimulus.Text = stimulusLabels[i];
            thisStimulus.stimulsLabel =  thisStimulus.addMyLabel();
            thisStimulus.stimulsLabel.Click += new EventHandler(myLabel_Click2);

            Controls.Add(thisStimulus.stimulsLabel);

        }
    }
```

The issue is that I need each of the labels to return a number (i.e. myNumber integer) when clicked on.
But when I have added this click event:

```
thisStimulus.stimulsLabel.Click += new EventHandler(myLabel_Click2);
```

All I got is that the sender is null (within the method of myLabel_Click2)  :(

Any suggestion on how I get the program to identify which one of the objects has created this label? More specifically - I would like to retrieve the variable myNumber of the object that created the label I have just clicked on.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use an anonymous method like:

```
thisStimulus.StimulusLabel.Click += (sender) => 
{
     int number = thisStimulus.myNumber;
     // your code here ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. but.. I have tried it as well, but still messing around with a "floating" label that does not correlate to the stimulus. I still get thisStimulus as a null

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit from "Label" with:

```cs
public class MyLabel : Label
{
    public int myNumber { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Image myImage { get; set; }
    public int Pos_X { get; set; }
    public int Pos_Y { get; set; }
    public DateTime responseTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime endResponseTime { get; set; }
    public int currentTracker { get; set; }
    public bool clickTypeTrueFalse { get; set; }
}
```

And your CreateLabels function:

```cs
private void CreateLabels(int[]Positions1, int[]Positions2, string[] stimulusLabels)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Positions1.Length; i++)
    {
        MyLabel label = new Stimulus();
        //All other field inits
        label.Click += myLabel_Click2;

        Controls.Add(label);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nir.Thank you for your reply.
I have tried to implement it, but it keeps throwing an error saying that explicit conversion already exists... Do you think it's because I'm trying to override an existing System Label class?

Comment: You get a compile error? I tried it in a simple stripped down project and it was fine

Comment: Hi Nir. I'll give it a go again. I have probably missed something. Once I'll get back from work I'll do again and come back. Thanks though for your support :)